# Is there a way to delete Main.storyboard in SwiftUI macOS project?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swiftui

I am currently building a macOS project using SwiftUI. When I create the project, Main.storyboard file gets created automatically. I found some solution ([here](https://medium.com/@sapa.tech/xcode-11-3-remove-storyboard-from-project-6c48c9d11123)) to remove Main.storyboard file after setting the user interface as storyboard. But I did not find a way to delete the Main.storyboard when the user interface is SwiftUI. Any help would be appreciated! I have attached a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hdy1O.png) of the macOS project with SwiftUI as the interface.

Comment: Why do you want to delete it? It is just for the MenuBar

Comment: Having storyboard file in a swiftui project does not seems to be right for me.. for the project which I am working on, doesn't need a Menu Bar..

Comment: Every macOS application does have a menu bar at the top.

Comment: okay.. here is the thing: There is a way to delete the storyboard for projects created using storyboard as the interface.. i am still curious to know if there is a similar option for SwiftUI user interface..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Remove the main storyboard in a SwiftUI app (macOS)

Yes, here are the steps:

1. Delete the Main.storyboard from your project (to Trash)
2. Remove the `Main` reference in the **General** tab of your target:
   [image]
3. On macOS there should not be any reference to the storyboard in the plist file so nothing to do, but you need to remove the `@NSApplicationMain` from your App Delegate:
   [image: List item]
4. Now your project does not have any entry point so it will complain about a missing `_main` symbol. So create a `main.swift` file with the following content:

```swift
import AppKit

let app = NSApplication.shared
let delegate = AppDelegate()
app.delegate = delegate
app.run()
```

As others pointed out, you will lose the default menu of macOS (that's actually why I use this technique), so to create a menu programmatically add the following at the top of the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method of your AppDelegate to add what you need:

```swift
let appMenu = NSMenuItem()
appMenu.submenu = NSMenu()
appMenu.submenu?.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Quit", action: #selector(NSApplication.terminate(_:)), keyEquivalent: "q"))
let mainMenu = NSMenu(title: "My App")
mainMenu.addItem(appMenu)
NSApplication.shared.mainMenu = mainMenu
```

Cheers